# Magento category add page description,Meta Keywords,Meta Description and image remove

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Here i want to hide the category add/edit page some of the fields.

Fields

1. Description
2. Meta Description
3. Meta Keywords
4. Meta Description
5. Image

I tried to hide but unfortunately i can not able to find the file,so kindly suggest the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please add bellow code in file** (Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs) (line : 124)

```
if(in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode() ,array('description','meta_description','image','meta_keywords'))) {
    continue;
}
```

Make sure file pull in core to local folder